# How can you view your private activity in github?

Tags: github

When I am logged in to [github](https://github.com/) and visit my profile it shows my **Public Activity**. I do not see any way to view my *private* activity. I understand others should not be able to see it, but when I am logged in, is there any way for me to view my own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

click on your name, in the top right banner.

Let me revert that: you are right.. only public activity

Ok, found it... Login, then look at the page.
2nd top banner: News feed/Your actions/Pull request/...

Comment: Totally agree.  I used it all the time

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GitHub API to get access to your own private activity feed.

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/feeds/

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a set of Powershell cmdlets that I call Posh-GitHub -- they're in the early stages, but you can get this info using the Get-GitHubEvents cmdlet

https://github.com/Iristyle/Posh-GitHub

Answer (score 0):

You can on a per repository basis:

https://github.com/xxx/yyy/commits?author=username